# how to align widths for input-group-addon

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

Hi I have the following html file, which consists of 3 input options. As follows

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dashboard_assigngroup_popup.html">

    <div class="modal-header modal-header2">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Assign Chart Group</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table">
            {%verbatim %}

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group" style="padding:1%;">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Chart title</span>
                        <select type="input" class="form-control" ng-model="final_data.info" ng-options="m.id as m.title for m in chartlist" required ng-cloak>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group" style="padding:1%;">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Chart group</span>
                        <select type="input" class="form-control" ng-model="final_data.group" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in chartgrouplist" required ng-cloak>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <div class="input-group" style="padding:1%;">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Order </span>
                        <input type="input" class="form-control" placeholder="Order" ng-model="final_data.orderg">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="submit()" id="submit">Save</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-grey" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Discard</button>
                    </div>
        </table>
        {% endverbatim %}
    </div>

</script>
```

But the  input-group-addons are not aligned. Tried to align using CSS, but failed to do so. How can I align this  input-group-addons? Any suggestions guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear... May be you can give a codepen or jsFiddle?
You are just using <td> elements, and spans inside them - Unless, your css for <td> mess up alignments, all your span.input-group-addon elements should be left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Then solution lies in your html

1. Each label together with its parent must be in a table cell
2. Each input option and its parent must be in a table cell

**here is a snippet (add a border to all `td` and see the alignment)**

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dashboard_assigngroup_popup.html"></script>
    <div class="modal-header modal-header2">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Assign Chart Group</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table">
            {%verbatim %}

            <tr>
                <td class="input-group" style="padding:1%;">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Chart title</span>
                        
                </td>
                <td>
                <select type="input" class="form-control" ng-model="final_data.info" ng-options="m.id as m.title for m in chartlist" required ng-cloak></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
              <span class="input-group-addon">Chart group</span>
              </td>
            <td>
              <select  class="input-group" style="padding:1%;"> </select>
            </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group" style="padding:1%;"></div>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">Order </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="input" class="form-control" placeholder="Order" ng-model="final_data.orderg">
                </td>                
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="submit()" id="submit">Save</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-grey" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Discard</button>
                    </div>
        </table>
        {% endverbatim %}
    </div>

</script>
```

Comment: Its not working repzero. Now the input-group-addon width going so long.

Comment: try using css to style your "input group add on width" to whatever width you would like.example 50px...i am assuming that template has some css standard styling...